# Create subdomains dynamically from URL parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns

I have shared hosting from GoDaddy. I want to create(illusion) sub-domains dynamically from URL parameters.

For e.g.
http://example.mydomain.com/value1/value2

points to

http://www.mydomain.com/?domain=example&m1=value1&m2=value2

I have created A wildcard DNS record. I also have added these rules in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?domain=%1&m1=$1&m2=$2 [P,L]
```

But when I open http://example.mydomain.com I get "pageok" as output.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm in hostinger.co and i want made the same, but my htaccess script don't work :/ if you can solve this, please helpme. My question is: [My Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32133016/dns-error-with-dynamic-subdomains-with-htaccess). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on shared hosting with GoDaddy, it’s probable they are only configuring their Apache install to pay attention to `www.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com` and nothing else via `NameVirtualHost`. You would have to see if it’s possible for them to accept any subdomain sent to `[subdomian].mydomain.com` and then send it to the main site script.