# DNS error with Dynamic subdomains with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns

i'm trying to implement dinamics subdomains for cityes, but this not work when a subdomain is used. My htaccess is:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.bisnet.com.co [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://bisnet.com.co/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.bisnetcolombia.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://bisnet.com.co/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.bisnet.co [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://bisnet.com.co/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Activar RewriteEngine

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 
#RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.bisnet\.com\.co
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.bisnet\.com\.co
Rewriterule ^([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9_]*) http://bisnet.com.co/index.php?categoria=$1&empresa=$3&ciudad=%1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.bisnet\.com\.co
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.bisnet\.com\.co
Rewriterule ^([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) http://bisnet.com.co/index.php?categoria=$1&ciudad=%1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.bisnet\.com\.co
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.bisnet\.com\.co
Rewriterule ^letra/([^/.]+) http://bisnet.com.co/index.php?categorias=$1&ciudad=%1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.bisnet\.com\.co
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.bisnet\.com\.co
Rewriterule ^buscar/(.+) http://bisnet.com.co/index.php?q=$1&ciudad=%1

Rewriterule ^nosotros/(.+) http://bisnet.com.co/index.php?interna=$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.bisnet\.com\.co
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.bisnet\.com\.co
RewriteRule ^ http://bisnet.com.co/index.php?ciudad=%1
</IfModule>
```

In http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ the test appear work fine, but in my server y get the error: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

the url's to test are:

```
http://bucaramanga.bisnet.com.co/
http://bucaramanga.bisnet.com.co/letra/a
http://bucaramanga.bisnet.com.co/166-restaurantes
http://bucaramanga.bisnet.com.co/166-restaurantes/355-la_casona_del_chingo
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you have DNS setup to point any subdomain to your server?

Comment: Thanks for you help :). Yes i've a CNAME record *.bisnet.com.co bisnet.com.co 1440